# On some examples of critical families

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, infinite-combinatorics

I'm reading the book on [Injective choice functions by Holz, Podewski and Steffens](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540172215), and I find it to be at the same time well written and quite difficult. It has almost no examples - and in quite a few situations I wasn't able to come up with examples myself (not due to lack of trying, but rather lack of skill). So that's what this thread is about.

A *covering* of a non-empty set $X$ is a collection ${\cal U} \subseteq ({\cal P}(X)\setminus\{\emptyset\})$ such that $\bigcup {\cal U} = X$. If ${\cal U}$ is a covering of $X$ then a function $f:{\cal U}\to X$ is called a *choice function* if $f(A)\in A$ for all $A\in {\cal U}$. A *marriage* is an injective choice function.

We say that ${\cal U}$ is *critial* if

1. there is a marriage $f:{\cal U}\to X$, and
2. every marriage $f:{\cal U}\to X$ is surjective.

I would like to see examples of the following:

1. Is there a critical covering on an infinite set $X$ that contains no singletons, and at least one member of the covering is infinite? (Noah Schweber demonstrated [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/243602/8628) that at least one member of any critical covering has to be finite.)
2. Is there a critical covering ${\cal U}$ on $\omega$ such that $$\bigcup \{F\in {\cal U}: F\text { is finite}\} \neq \omega$$?

**Edit** I added label graph-theory because marriages in this context are matchings in a bipartite graph.

Comment: For (1), can you let $X$ be $\mathbb{Z}$, and let $\mathcal{U}$ be $\mathbb{Z}$ along with each successive pair of integers?

Comment: For (2), can you let $\mathcal{U}$ be $\omega$ along with each set of the form $n \setminus \{0\}$, for $n \geq 2$?

Comment: Hi Paul -- thanks for your examples, can you put them in a  answer along with a hint of why they are critical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any fixed $n\in\mathbb N,$ there is a critical covering $\mathcal U$ of $\omega$ such that each finite member of $\mathcal U$ contains exactly $n$ elements, and one member of $\mathcal U$ is infinite; moreover, $\bigcup\{F\in\mathcal U:F\text{ is finite}\}\ne\omega.$

Namely, let
$$\omega=A\cup B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3\cup\cdots$$
where $A,B_1,B_2,B_3,\dots$ are pairwise disjoint sets, $|A|=1,$ and $|B_i|=n+1$ for each $i,$ and let
$$\mathcal U=\{\omega\}\cup\binom{B_1}n\cup\binom{B_2}n\cup\binom{B_3}n\cup\cdots.$$

Answer (score 1):

For (1), I think you can let $X$ be $\mathbb{Z}$ and let $\mathcal{U}$ be $\mathbb{Z}$ along with each successive pair of integers. Then, by symmetry, it doesn't matter which point you pick for $\mathbb{Z}$, but once you have picked this point all the other choices are determined by iteratively picking the one point remaining for those sets with one unpicked point left.

For (2), I think you can let $\mathcal{U}$ be $\omega$ along with each set of the form $n \setminus \{0\}$ for $n \geq 2$. Then the set $\{1\}$ has to pick $1$, the set $\{1,2\}$ has to pick $2$, and so on, leaving $\omega$ to pick $0$.